# How to identify a given string is hex color format

Tags: regex, colors

I'm looking for a regular expression to validate hex colors in ASP.NET C# and
am also looking code for validation on server side.

For instance: `#CCCCCC`

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Note: This is strictly for *validation*, i.e. accepting a valid hex color. For actual *parsing* you won't get the individual parts out of this.

```
^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$
```

For ARGB:

```
^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3,4}){1,2}$
```

Dissection:

```
^              anchor for start of string
#              the literal #
(              start of group
 ?:            indicate a non-capturing group that doesn't generate backreferences
 [0-9a-fA-F]   hexadecimal digit
 {3}           three times
)              end of group
{1,2}          repeat either once or twice
$              anchor for end of string
```

This will match an arbitrary hexadecimal color value that can be used in CSS, such as `#91bf4a` or `#f13`.

Comment: I thought valid colour was 3 * a 1/2 combo... so /^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}){3}$/ Both ways seem to work.

Comment: @MichaelDausmann: Nope, yours would accept anything between 3 and 6 hex digits.

Comment: @Joey very helpful the step by step explanation. thanks

Comment: This regex is very useful in the creation of an example program that my company uses for onboarding new developers. As an old-school Perl programmer, I was impressed to see that some younger developers had figured out look-ahead assertions in more modern programming languages. After seeing the same regex in a few other people's submissions, I finally decided to google it and see that they've just figured out how to search SO 

Comment: Little modification to handle both RGB and ARGB : "^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3,4}$"

Comment: regex seems also match `#a14dda4`, which is not a valid hex color

Comment: This regex fails for a hex value of 7 characters like #123b567. For the correct way, inverse the repeating groups ^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3,4}$

Answer (score 25):

Minor disagreement with the other solution. I'd say

```
^#(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3})$
```

The reason is that this (correctly) captures the individual RGB components. The other expression broke #112233 in three parts, '#' 112 233. The syntax is actually '#' (RR GG BB) | (R G B)

The slight disadvantage is more backtracking is required. When parsing #CCC you don't know that the second C is the green component until you hit the end of the string; when parsing #CCCCCC you don't know that the second C is still part of the red component until you see the 4th C.

It also works great for RGBA but the other solution doesn't

```js
const thisRegex = /#(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3,4})/g
document.write("#fff;ae#rvaerv c #fffaff---#afd #ffff".match(thisRegex))
// #fff,#fffaff,#afd,#ffff
```

the other solution doesn't recognize #fffaff well

```js
const theOtherSolutionRegex = /#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3,4}){1,2}/g
document.write("#fff;ae#rvaerv c #fffaff---#afd #ffff".match(theOtherSolutionRegex))
// #fff,#fffa,#afd,#ffff
```

Comment: This regex would also match #1234 and #12345. However, there can be only either 3 digits or 6 digits. This RE allows anything between 3 and 6 digits. If you truly wanted to capture the correct structure, then you'd have to use `#([1-9a-fA-F]{3}|[1-9a-fA-F]{6})`. If you want to capture the individual color components it gets more complex (your suggestion doesn't do that as well).

Comment: For pure validation purposes (i. e. whether a value is actually a possible and correct one) however, I find it easier to look at the apparent structure of the string and not at the specified one. At least in this case the resulting RE is simpler.

Comment: @MSalters this is still not quite right, as it returns a match for the last 3 digits of #FFFF. Adding an extra set of brackets: `^#(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3})$` fixes it.

Comment: Indeed, the `|` wasn't bracketed so it looked for `^#FFFFFFF` or `FFF$`. Fixed.

Comment: isn't `([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}` equivalent to `[0-9a-fA-F]{6}`?

Comment: @chharvey: No. `( )` is a _capturing group_. `( ){3}` are three capturing groups. `[0-9a-fA-F]{6}` has no capturing groups at all.

Comment: @MSalters but what difference does it make if you don’t backreference the capturing group?

Comment: Who said anything about parsing the string or identifying the colors? The original poster only needs to identify an octothorpe followed by 3 or 6 hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 10):

all answers mentioned RGB format,
here is regex for ARGB format:

```
^#[0-9a-fA-F]{8}$|#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$|#[0-9a-fA-F]{4}$|#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}$
```

Answer (score 9):

This should match any `#rgb`, `#rgba`, `#rrggbb`, and `#rrggbbaa` syntax:

```
/^#(?:(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|(?:[\da-f]{4}){1,2})$/i
```

break down:

```
^            // start of line
#            // literal pound sign, followed by
(?:          // either:
  (?:          // a non-capturing group of:
    [\da-f]{3}   // exactly 3 of: a single digit or a letter 'a'–'f'
  ){1,2}       // repeated exactly 1 or 2 times
|            // or:
  (?:          // a non-capturing group of:
    [\da-f]{4}   // exactly 4 of: a single digit or a letter 'a'–'f'
  ){1,2}       // repeated exactly 1 or 2 times
)
$            // end of line
i            // ignore case (let 'A'–'F' match 'a'–'f')
```

---

Notice that the above is *not* equivalent to this syntax, which is incorrect:

```
/^#(?:[\da-f]{3,4}){1,2}$/i
```

This would allow a group of 3 followed by a group of 4, such as `#1234567`, which is not a valid hex color.

Comment: Thanks @chharvey comprehensive for all possibilities

Answer (score 5):

This if you want to accept named colors and rgb(a,b,c) too. The final "i" is for case insensitive.

**HTML colors** (#123, rgb not accepted)

```
/^(#[a-f0-9]{6}|black|green|silver|gray|olive|white|yellow|maroon|navy|red|blue|purple|teal|fuchsia|aqua)$/i
```

**CSS colors** (#123, rgb accepted)

```
/^(#[a-f0-9]{6}|#[a-f0-9]{3}|rgb *\( *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *\)|rgba *\( *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *\)|black|green|silver|gray|olive|white|yellow|maroon|navy|red|blue|purple|teal|fuchsia|aqua)$/i
```

Comment: but there are more colors supported in html like darkturquoise , lightgoldenrodyellow and so

Comment: @MendonAshwini yes. There are 140 of them new ones. You can write them all at the end of the regexp, delimited by |

Comment: yeah.. i checked on https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/. But is that the oly way to varify it? Does java provide any library?

Answer (score 4):

Based on MSalters' answer, but preventing an incorrect match, the following works

```
^#(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3})$
```

Or for an optional hash `#` symbol:

```
^#?(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3})$
```

And without back references being generated:

```
^#?(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]){3})$
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby

In Ruby, you have access to the `\h` (hexadecimal) character class. You also have to take more care of line endings, hence the `\A...\z` instead of the more common `^...$`

```
/\A#(\h{3}){1,2}\z/
```

This will match 3 or 6 hexadecimal characters following a #. So no RGBA. It's also case-insensitive, despite not having the `i` flag.

Comment: in ruby you also have `/\H/` which match non hexa characters, so you just have to negate the boolean (0 non hexa characters found by regex : it is valid hexa number)

ex: `!"FF000"[/\H/] # true` , `!"hello"[/\H/] # false`