# What is you favourite approach to check if a HTML COLOR is valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I use C# and ASP.NET 4 WebControls.

I have a TextBox on my page, User can input a HTML Color in HEXADECIMAL format (ff0000) or in HTML Format ("Red").

My initial thought was that would be too difficult writing a RegEx able to validate this User's input, so I come up with an idea to write a simple method to check if the inputted color can be translated to a valid one to be used the context of System.Drawing.

Below my code. It returns a Bool DataType stating if the operation was successful.
It is working fine for now but I would like to know:

- If my method was well written?
- Do you know a better approach?

Thanks for your consideration.

```
using SD = System.Drawing;

protected static bool CheckValidFormatHtmlColor(string inputColor)
        {
            try
            {
                SD.Color myColor = SD.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(inputColor);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code is the most pragmatic I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My gut says to mistrust Microsoft when it comes to getting something like an HTML colour code right. I've found what appears to be [the source code to the class](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Advanced/ColorTranslator@cs/1/ColorTranslator@cs) you are using and it accepts a lot of things that are not HTML colours.

A regex then checking against a list sounds like the sensible way forward for this.

After trimming white space, check if it matches `/^#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}$/`, if it doesn't, compare it to the [list of 16 colours](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.5) that appear in HTML.

Comment: Thanks David for your regx--- but what do you think about by method?

Comment: I've added a paragraph at the top having done some investigation into the class you are using.

Comment: Thanks David I will try out ad let you know for sure. Thanks for now.

Comment: My gut feeling says that this method instead accepts a *CSS* colour value. It's just that around 2000 when it was written the distinction in many people's minds probably wasn't as pronounced.

Answer (score 16):

Exception handling is heavy and should be used as a last resort and only for actual exceptions.  Try this. It checks for a valid html hex color and then tries named colors.

```
protected static bool CheckValidFormatHtmlColor(string inputColor)
{
       //regex from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1636354/2343
       if (Regex.Match(inputColor, "^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$").Success)
           return true;

       var result = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(inputColor);
       return result.IsKnownColor;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One regex for all, just for the fun. The i at the end is for case insensitivity. Probably not fast, but "one shot".

**HTML colors**

```
/^(#[a-f0-9]{6}|black|green|silver|gray|olive|white|yellow|maroon|navy|red|blue|purple|teal|fuchsia|aqua)$/i
```

**CSS colors**

```
/^(#[a-f0-9]{6}|#[a-f0-9]{3}|(rgb|hsl) *\( *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *\)|(rgba|hsla) *\( *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *, *[0-9]{1,3}%? *\)|black|green|silver|gray|olive|white|yellow|maroon|navy|red|blue|purple|teal|fuchsia|aqua)$/i
```

Comment: you missed the hsl and hsla color schemes

Comment: @SuryaPratap right! I guess just duplicating the rgb & rgba pieces might do the trick. Or also adding inner (rgb|hsl) and (rgba|hsla) switches..

Comment: there is also 4 and 8 length hex for alpha. should be "#[a-f0-9]{8}|#[a-f0-9]{6}|#[a-f0-9]{3,4}"?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var regexColorCode = new Regex("^#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}$");
string colorCode = "#FFFF00";

if (!regexColorCode.IsMatch(colorCode.Trim()))
{   
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert" ,"alert('Enter a valid Color Code');", true);
}
else
{
    //do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Main` method

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> testColors = new List<string>
    {
        null
        ,""
        ,"#00"
        ,"#000"
        ,"#12345aa"
        ,"#fff1az"
        ,"#FFDFD991"
        ,"ajdoajsdoijsaod"
    };

    foreach (var color in testColors)
    {
        bool result = IsHtmlColor(color);
        Console.WriteLine($"IsHtmlColor({color}) => {result}");
    }

}
```

The helper method

```cs
public static bool IsHtmlColor(string hexa)
{
    try
    {
        // using System.Windows.Media;
        return ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(hexa) is Color;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.