# How to check if a string is a valid hex color representation?

Tags: javascript, colors

For example:

`AA33FF` = valid hex color

`Z34FF9` = invalid hex color (has Z in it)

`AA33FF11` = invalid hex color (has extra characters)

Comment: depending on context, the last one could be a valid color, if it includes alpha in `AARRGGBB` format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify a given string is hex color format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636350/how-to-identify-a-given-string-is-hex-color-format)

Answer (score 421, accepted):

Without transparent support:

```
/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test('#AABBCC')
```

With transparent support :

```
/^#[0-9A-F]{6}[0-9a-f]{0,2}$/i.test('#AABBCC80')
```

To elaborate:

`^          ->` match beginning
`#          ->` a hash
`[0-9A-F]   ->` any integer from 0 to 9 and any letter from A to F
`{6}        ->` the previous group appears exactly 6 times
`[0-9a-f]{0,2}   ->` adding support for transparent ( 00..FF)
`$          ->` match end
`i          ->` ignore case

If you need support for 3-character HEX codes (no transparent supported) , use the following:

```
/^#([0-9A-F]{3}){1,2}$/i.test('#ABC')
```

The only difference here is that

```
 [0-9A-F]{6}
```

is replaced with

```
([0-9A-F]{3}){1,2}
```

This means that instead of matching exactly 6 characters, it will match exactly 3 characters, but only 1 or 2 times. Allowing `ABC` and `AABBCC`, but not `ABCD`

**Combined solution :**

```
var reg=/^#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i;
console.log(reg.test('#ABC')); //true
console.log(reg.test('#AABBCC')); //true
```

Comment: By definition this is correct, but codes with a length of 3 are valid for browser interpretation, too. `color: #f00;` will be interpreted as red (#ff0000) aswell.

Comment: or another form: `/^#[0-9a-f]{3}(?:[0-9a-f]{3})?$/i.test("#f00")`

Comment: How to use this? I am getting the input hexadecimal color from a JS prompt.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahithe prompt returns a value of string which you can test

Comment: I added an option in mine to make the '#' character optional. (I just added a question mark after the pound char)  If user is entering this hex value they may or may not know to include the pound char.  with modification: /(^#?[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test('f00')

Comment: I would also add `/^#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i` to the mix.

Comment: @AndresSepar `/^#[0-9A-F]{3,6}$/i.test('#aabb')` also passes, but `#aabb` isn't a valid hex color.

Comment: var isOk = /^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/i.test('#aabbcc');  @RomanBoiko this is right! Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, I tested with this; #010A
Should this be accepted, as it isn't?

Comment: To include #AARRGGBB format (in addition to #RGB and #RRGGBB already covered): `/^#(([A-F0-9]{2}){3,4}|[A-F0-9]{3})$/i`  (and non-capturing version for improved efficiency: `^#(?:(?:[A-F0-9]{2}){3,4}|[A-F0-9]{3})$`).  https://regexr.com/3p38r

Comment: Great answer! How to make the '#' optional? is this ok? `/^#?([0-9A-F]{3}){1,2}$/i.test('ABC')`

Comment: Awesome work! It really works for both 3 and 6 hexadeximal codes.

Comment: Use this to make it work for 3,4,6,8 hex:

3: #f00 (red using single char per color element)
4: #f000 (red using single char per color element with alpha channel at 0)
6: #ff0000 (red using two chars per color element)
8: #ff000000 (red using two chars per color element with alpha channel at 0)

Comment: @MaximPaperno You’re missing `,4` in `{3}` (it should be `{3,4}`) in both of your examples to match `#abcd`.

Answer (score 43):

```js
// regular function
function isHexColor (hex) {
  return typeof hex === 'string'
      && hex.length === 6
      && !isNaN(Number('0x' + hex))
}

// or as arrow function (ES6+)
isHexColor = hex => typeof hex === 'string' && hex.length === 6 && !isNaN(Number('0x' + hex))

console.log(isHexColor('AABBCC'))   // true
console.log(isHexColor('AABBCC11')) // false
console.log(isHexColor('XXBBCC'))   // false
console.log(isHexColor('AAXXCC'))   // false
```

This answer used to throw false positives because instead of `Number('0x' + hex)`, it used `parseInt(hex, 16)`.
`parseInt()` will parse from the beginning of the string until it reaches a character that isn't included in the radix (`16`). This means it could parse strings like 'AAXXCC', because it starts with 'AA'.

`Number()`, on the other hand, will only parse if the whole string matches the radix. Now, `Number()` doesn't take a radix parameter, but luckily, you can prefix number literals to get a number in other radii.

Here's a table for clarification:

```
╭─────────────┬────────────┬────────┬───────────────────╮
│ Radix       │ Characters │ Prefix │ Will output 27    │
╞═════════════╪════════════╪════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ Binary      │ 0-1        │ 0b     │ Number('0b11011') │
│ Octal       │ 0-7        │ 0o     │ Number('0o33')    │
│ Decimal     │ 0-9        │ -      │ -                 │
│ Hexadecimal │ 0-9A-F     │ 0x     │ Number('0x1b')    │
╰─────────────┴────────────┴────────┴───────────────────╯
```

Comment: +1 bcs much better to read and faster to understand than a regex

Comment: @Chris 'because' is also much better to read and faster to understand than 'bcs' ;-)

Comment: @Chris: i got so used to 'bcs' for me doesnt make a difference. anyways my comment was meant as a compliment so be happy.

Comment: This is wrong: parseInt('abcZab', 16) will output number and pass the test

Comment: @fflorent Because `parseInt` will take `"abcZab"`, find that `"Z"` is invalid (for radix 16), and ignore it and anything after it. It then takes the beginning `"abc"` and convert it to `2748` (which is also the result of `parseInt("abcZab", 16)`, proving that's the logic happening). As the name implies, `parseInt` **parses** a string. Just like if you were parsing a number with units on it with a radix of 10, like `parseInt("10px", 10)`, you'd get `10`. You can see it described here: http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.2 (step 11)

Comment: @fflorent Really appreciate the honesty! +1 for that!

Comment: you can compare the result with `source.ToString(16)` and you don't get false positives anymore.

Comment: Why only compare with length of 6? Hex color code length can be 3 as well.

Comment: Add a length check and it works and is probably easier to read than a regex

Comment: You can resolve the issue of abcZab by splitting the string into characters and applying the condition on every character. Then it picks Z up and returns false.
`s.split('').every(char=>!isNaN(parseInt(char, 16)));`

Comment: "ddffaaa" returns false positive

Answer (score 8):

This can be a complicated problem.  After several attempts I came up with a fairly clean solution.  Let the browswer do the the work for you.

Step 1: Create a div with border-style set to none.  The div can be positioned off screen or it can be any div on your page that doesn't use the borders.

Step 2: Set the border color to an empty string. The code might look something like this:

```
e=document.getElementbyId('mydiv');
e.style.borderColor="";
```

Step 3: Set the border color to the color you aren't sure about.

```
e.style.borderColor=testcol;
```

Step 4: Check to see if the color actually got changed.  If testcol is invalid, no change will occur.

```
col2=e.style.borderColor;
if(col2.length==0) {alert("Bad Color!");}
```

Step 5: Clean up after yourself by setting the color back to an empty string.

```
e.style.borderColor="";
```

The Div:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="border-style:none; position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px;"></div>
```

Now the JavaScript function:

```
function GoodColor(color)
{
   var color2="";
   var result=true;
   var e=document.getElementById('mydiv');
   e.style.borderColor="";
   e.style.borderColor=color;
   color2=e.style.borderColor;
   if (color2.length==0){result=false;}
   e.style.borderColor="";
   return result;
}
```

In this case, the function is returning a true/false answer to the question, the other option is to have it return a valid color value.  Your original color value, the value from borderColor or an empty string in place of invalid colors.

Comment: IMO, this isn't a clean solution in the least

Comment: IMO, this could easily be the most complicated solution.

Comment: This can only be implemented in a browser environment (is not a pure-javascript solution)

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to use it in HTML Try using this pattern Directly :

```
 pattern="^#+([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})$"
```

like

```
<input id="hex" type="text" pattern="^#+([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})$" />
```

It will give a validation to match the requested format.

Answer (score 2):

To write a good validation, I started from writing the **positive** and **negative** tests, establishing a baseline for which my validation code
should work by, and mixing a few of the good answers here and my own logic, I came up with this:

```js
/^#(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){3,4}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{3})$/.test(hex)
```

[image: http://www.regexplained.co.uk]

### Tests Cases:

(hopefully covering over 90% of cases)

```js
const isValidHex = hex => /^#(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){3,4}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{3})$/.test(hex);

// positive tests
[
  '#ffffff',   // 6-characters, valid range
  '#ffffff99', // 9-characters, last 2 for alpha channel
  '#fff',      // 3-characters
].forEach(c => console.log(isValidHex(c), c));

console.log('\nshould fail:\n\n');

// negative tests
[
  '#invalid',   // obviously not a color
  '#f',         // 1 character is not enough
  '#ff',        // 2 characters is not enough
  '#ffff',      // 4 characters is not enough
  '#fffff',     // 5 characters is not enough
  '#fffffff',   // 7 characters is not enough
  '#ffffff999', // 9 characters are too many
  '#ggg',       // HEX is base 16, so characters beyond "F" (16) are invalid
].forEach(c => console.log(isValidHex(c), c))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validColor(color){
  var $div = $("<div>");
  $div.css("border", "1px solid "+color);
  return ($div.css("border-color")!="")
}
```

https://gist.github.com/dustinpoissant/22ce25c9e536bb2c5a2a363601ba261c

*Note: This requires jQuery*

This works for **ALL** color types not just hex values. It also does **not** append unnecessary elements to the DOM tree.

Comment: Nice and easy and works very well. Personally I added if(hexString.indexOf('#') == -1) { return false; } to check for a hash as a rudimentary check that color was a hex value

Answer (score 1):

If you need a function to tell you if a color is valid, you might as well have it give you something useful -- the computed values of that color -- and return null when it is not a valid color. Here's my stab at a compatible (Chrome54 & MSIE11) function to get the RGBA values of a "color" in any of the formats --be it 'green', or '#FFF', or '#89abcd', or 'rgb(0,0,128)', or 'rgba( 0, 128, 255, 0.5)'.

```
/* getRGBA:
  Get the RGBA values of a color.
  If input is not a color, returns NULL, else returns an array of 4 values:
   red (0-255), green (0-255), blue (0-255), alpha (0-1)
*/
function getRGBA(value) {
  // get/create a 0 pixel element at the end of the document, to use to test properties against the client browser
  var e = document.getElementById('test_style_element');
  if (e == null) {
    e = document.createElement('span');
    e.id = 'test_style_element';
    e.style.width = 0;
    e.style.height = 0;
    e.style.borderWidth = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(e);
  }

  // use the browser to get the computed value of the input
  e.style.borderColor = '';
  e.style.borderColor = value;
  if (e.style.borderColor == '') return null;
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(e);
  var c
  if (typeof computedStyle.borderBottomColor != 'undefined') {
    // as always, MSIE has to make life difficult
    c = window.getComputedStyle(e).borderBottomColor;
  } else {
    c = window.getComputedStyle(e).borderColor;
  }
  var numbersAndCommas = c.replace(new RegExp('[^0-9.,]+','g'),'');
  var values = numbersAndCommas.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    values[i] = Number(values[i]);
  if (values.length == 3) values.push(1);
  return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a length check to make sure that you don't get a false positive

```
function isValidHex(testNum){
  let validHex = false;
  let numLength = testNum.length;
  let parsedNum = parseInt(testNum, 16);
  if(!isNan(parsedNum) && parsedNum.length===numLength){
     validHex = true;
  }
  return validHex;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try a different perspective. My rules were : 1)Arbitrarily long sequence of hex characters, 2)Usage of either "0x" or "#" at the front of a sequence, or 3)Just a hex number or string. I'm thinking back to when binhex was one of the big programs. Binhex would create really large files that could be transferred to anyplace and then made back in to whatever file it was you converted. These files would have 80 characters followed by a return. So in this function I look for returns and take them back out first. Modified the function so it looks for both the "\n" and "\r". Here is the code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  isHex(). Is this a hex string/value?
//  Arguments   :   0   =   Item to test
//                  1   =   V(alue) or S(tring). Default is STRING.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function isHex()
{
    var p = 0;
    var re1 = /(\n|\r)+/g;
    var re2 = /[\Wg-zG-Z]/;
    var re3 = /v/i;
//
//  Make sure the string is really a string.
//
    var s = arguments[0];
    if( typeof s != "string" ){ s = s.toString(); }
//
//  Check if this is a hex VALUE
//  and NOT a hex STRING.
//
    var opt = arguments[1];
    if( re3.test(opt) && (s.length % 2 > 0) ){ return "false"; }
//
//  Remove any returns. BinHex files can be megabytes in length with 80
//  column information. So we have to remove all returns first.
//
    s.replace( re1, "" );
//
//  IF they send us something with the universal "0x" or the HTML "#" on the
//  front of it - we have to FIRST move where we look at the string.
//
    if( s.substr(0,1) == "#" ){ p = 1; }
        else if( s.substr(0,2).toLowerCase() == "0x" ){ p = 2; }

   if( re2.test(s.substr(p,s.length)) ){ return "false"; }

   return "true";
}

alert("HELLO There!");
alert(isHex("abcdef"));
alert(isHex("0x83464"));
alert(isHex("#273847"));
alert(isHex("This is a test"));
alert(isHex(0x5346));
```

I have purposefully left the return values as strings but all you have to do is to remove the double quotes and the function will then just return TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

If ARGB is expected to be supported, the supported hexadecimal digits are 3, 4, 6, 8.

```
const isColor = (strColor) => {
  return /^#(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){3,4}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{3,4})$/.test(strColor)
}
```

Note that `{2}` should precede `{3,4}` to ensure that the **7-digit** hexadecimal can be correctly checked as **false**.