# In Javascript Regex, how do I validate that a string is a valid hexadecimal colour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given a string like `#fff443` or `#999999`

How do I verify that the string has:

- 7 characters, with the first one being a hash
- no symbols in the string besides the hash in the beginning

Comment: there are many ways to check with different structures : see my advanced answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027423/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-hex-color-representation/8027444#8027444

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that you are matching against a css color:

```
function isValidColor(str) {
    return str.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null;
}
```

To elaborate:

`^` match beginning
`#` a hash
`[a-f0-9]` any letter from a-f and 0-9
`{6}` the previous group appears exactly 6 times
`$` match end
`i` ignore case

Comment: @RoyiNamir: What doesn't this cover, according to the OP's strict requirements?

Comment: @qiao  : the fact that he also doesnt know that a hex can be `#aca`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That is beyond the point of the question. The OP is really just validating a string, which happens to contain a 6 digit hex. If the OP cared about `#aca` or `aquamarine` (assuming this is for a color) he would have said so. Read beyond just the question title.

Comment: I recommend to use `/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i`.exec(str)`, in case the supplied argument is not a string.

Comment: @qiao also next time use test and not match . its much faster.

Comment: I would like to add that I appreciate you explaining the regex. Understanding regular expressions is the most difficult part, copy/pasting them is easy :) If everyone did this there would be 80% less questions here about how to write a specific regex.

Comment: `/^#[a-f0-9]{6}|#[a-f0-9]{3}$/i` helps if you only need a valid hex color