# If color value is not valid - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, rgb

I have a problem with my JavaScript code 
if you enter the wrong code ( color value)  then it must be black.
but when I enter somthing like "blablabla" then it will be that I typed the last for exemple:
I write Red then it will be a red circle, but after that when I write blablabla will be red too, 
I just want that when I write a wrong color word it will be Black
I Think that I have to write an rgb code so the funktion will check if I write right or wrong

```
function getPos(canvas, event){

    var a = new Number();
    var b = new Number();
    var canvas= document.getElementById("can1");

    if (event.a != undefined && event.b != undefined)
    {
      a = event.a;
      b = event.b;
    }
    else
    {
      a = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
          document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      b = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
          document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    a -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    b -= canvas.offsetTop;




    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var color1 = document.getElementById('color');
    var size = document.getElementById('size');
    ctx.beginPath();

    if ( size.value > 0)
        {
        ctx.arc(a,b,size.value, 275*(Math.PI/180), 635*(Math.PI/180), false);
        }
    else
        {
        ctx.arc(a,b,15, 275*(Math.PI/180), 635*(Math.PI/180), false);
        } 




    if (color1.value.length < 0)
        {   
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";

        }

    else if (color1.value.length == 0) 
        {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        }

    else
        {
        ctx.fillStyle = color1.value; 
        }



        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        window.localStorage['IMG'] = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

the problem is here I guess:

```
if (color1.value.length < 0)
        {   
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";

        }

    else if (color1.value.length == 0) 
        {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        }

    else
        {
        ctx.fillStyle = color1.value; 
        }
```

Comment: `color1.value.length` can't be less than `0`. There's also nothing which would validate the given color name in your code.

Comment: exactly, I tried with 1 but it will be just the same problem so I dont know how to write a code that checking the color's names and when i write a wrong it will be Standard or Black.!

Comment: What's the difference between "wrong code" and "blablabla"?

Comment: what I mean is when I type wrong color code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for a valid hex or for color names. This solution is build out of two answers and is written by heart:

- [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573141/1456376)
- [How to check if a string is a valid hex color representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8027444/1456376)

---

```
function colorNameToHex(color) {
    var colors = {
        "aliceblue":"#f0f8ff","antiquewhite":"#faebd7","aqua":"#00ffff","aquamarine":"#7fffd4","azure":"#f0ffff","beige":"#f5f5dc","bisque":"#ffe4c4","black":"#000000","blanchedalmond":"#ffebcd","blue":"#0000ff","blueviolet":"#8a2be2","brown":"#a52a2a","burlywood":"#deb887","cadetblue":"#5f9ea0","chartreuse":"#7fff00","chocolate":"#d2691e","coral":"#ff7f50","cornflowerblue":"#6495ed","cornsilk":"#fff8dc","crimson":"#dc143c","cyan":"#00ffff","darkblue":"#00008b","darkcyan":"#008b8b","darkgoldenrod":"#b8860b","darkgray":"#a9a9a9","darkgreen":"#006400","darkkhaki":"#bdb76b","darkmagenta":"#8b008b","darkolivegreen":"#556b2f","darkorange":"#ff8c00","darkorchid":"#9932cc","darkred":"#8b0000","darksalmon":"#e9967a","darkseagreen":"#8fbc8f","darkslateblue":"#483d8b","darkslategray":"#2f4f4f","darkturquoise":"#00ced1","darkviolet":"#9400d3","deeppink":"#ff1493","deepskyblue":"#00bfff","dimgray":"#696969","dodgerblue":"#1e90ff","firebrick":"#b22222","floralwhite":"#fffaf0","forestgreen":"#228b22","fuchsia":"#ff00ff","gainsboro":"#dcdcdc","ghostwhite":"#f8f8ff","gold":"#ffd700","goldenrod":"#daa520","gray":"#808080","green":"#008000","greenyellow":"#adff2f","honeydew":"#f0fff0","hotpink":"#ff69b4","indianred":"#cd5c5c","indigo":"#4b0082","ivory":"#fffff0","khaki":"#f0e68c","lavender":"#e6e6fa","lavenderblush":"#fff0f5","lawngreen":"#7cfc00","lemonchiffon":"#fffacd","lightblue":"#add8e6","lightcoral":"#f08080","lightcyan":"#e0ffff","lightgoldenrodyellow":"#fafad2","lightgrey":"#d3d3d3","lightgreen":"#90ee90","lightpink":"#ffb6c1","lightsalmon":"#ffa07a","lightseagreen":"#20b2aa","lightskyblue":"#87cefa","lightslategray":"#778899","lightsteelblue":"#b0c4de","lightyellow":"#ffffe0","lime":"#00ff00","limegreen":"#32cd32","linen":"#faf0e6","magenta":"#ff00ff","maroon":"#800000","mediumaquamarine":"#66cdaa","mediumblue":"#0000cd","mediumorchid":"#ba55d3","mediumpurple":"#9370d8","mediumseagreen":"#3cb371","mediumslateblue":"#7b68ee","mediumspringgreen":"#00fa9a","mediumturquoise":"#48d1cc","mediumvioletred":"#c71585","midnightblue":"#191970","mintcream":"#f5fffa","mistyrose":"#ffe4e1","moccasin":"#ffe4b5","navajowhite":"#ffdead","navy":"#000080","oldlace":"#fdf5e6","olive":"#808000","olivedrab":"#6b8e23","orange":"#ffa500","orangered":"#ff4500","orchid":"#da70d6","palegoldenrod":"#eee8aa","palegreen":"#98fb98","paleturquoise":"#afeeee","palevioletred":"#d87093","papayawhip":"#ffefd5","peachpuff":"#ffdab9","peru":"#cd853f","pink":"#ffc0cb","plum":"#dda0dd","powderblue":"#b0e0e6","purple":"#800080","red":"#ff0000","rosybrown":"#bc8f8f","royalblue":"#4169e1","saddlebrown":"#8b4513","salmon":"#fa8072","sandybrown":"#f4a460","seagreen":"#2e8b57","seashell":"#fff5ee","sienna":"#a0522d","silver":"#c0c0c0","skyblue":"#87ceeb","slateblue":"#6a5acd","slategray":"#708090","snow":"#fffafa","springgreen":"#00ff7f","steelblue":"#4682b4","tan":"#d2b48c","teal":"#008080","thistle":"#d8bfd8","tomato":"#ff6347","turquoise":"#40e0d0","violet":"#ee82ee","wheat":"#f5deb3","white":"#ffffff","whitesmoke":"#f5f5f5","yellow":"#ffff00","yellowgreen":"#9acd32"
    };

    if (typeof colors[color.toLowerCase()] != 'undefined')
        return colors[color.toLowerCase()];

    return false;
}

function checkHex(color) {
    return /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(color);
}

var color = color1.value;

if (checkHex(color) || colorNameToHex(color)) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, the problem is i cant creat Another funktion, I have to set the code in same funktion in >> function getPos(canvas, event)

Comment: Should work if you copy that into the other function, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ChGxM/

Comment: YOU ÄR A FU*** GENUS, thank you man , it works now thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the entered color text then compare it with below format-

```
var isValidColor  = /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test('Your color code here')
```

for example-

```
var isValidColor  = /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test('#aabbcc')
```