# How to prevent color convert crash (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, colors, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a bot on discord where every user can pick their own color for the bot to display whenever they're using it. So far everything is working ok. However when entering some specific characters into the `.setColor()` on the embed it crashes the script and says there were a Color conversion error. I've tried putting 0x in front, # in front. But no matter what the script seems to crash when trying to put in "ZZZZZZ" as the color code. I'm not asking this because I want to use weird colors, just to make sure the bot doesn't crash because some idiot using it wants some strange color, or is just trying to crash it on purpose. I also know that it's possible to make it work since I've tested it on another bot. And here it doesn't crash the bot, but just sets a color, even though I entered "ZZZZZZ" as the color code. How do I make sure that the script doesn't crash / converts literally any combination of letters and numbers into a valid color?

Comment: Have you tried [searching for a valid hex code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852545/if-color-value-is-not-valid-javascript/14853006#14853006)?

Comment: @Tyler2P that doesn't include all discord color names (like BLURPLE)

Comment: @Tyler2P
I'm not trying to find a valid code. I need to make sure that whatever a user could imagine typing it won't crash the script

Comment: @Gabrielnigme20 the best way to make sure it doesn't crash is to validate the color

Comment: @MrMythical How would you do that?

Comment: @MrMythical
The user decides their own color simply by texting in chat. They could type literally anything. It'll take whatever they type and put it into a variable. Then paste that variable directly into ".setColor(userinput)"
That's why I need to make sure that whatever they decide to type it won't crash the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out, unfortunately I couldn't make the other code provided work. However I made this work:

```
    hex = args[0] // args[0] is the user defined input.

function isHexColor (hex) {
    return typeof hex === 'string'
        && hex.length === 6
        && !isNaN(Number('0x' + hex))
    }

    if (!isHexColor(hex) && !Object.keys(Discord.Constants.Colors).includes(hex.toUpperCase())) {
        message.reply('Please enter a valid HEX color to use'); return;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just validate the color!

```js
// colorArg is the argument for the wanted color
function checkHex(color) {
    return /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(color);
}

if (!checkHex(colorArg) && !Object.keys(Discord.Constants.Colors).includes(colorArg.toUpperCase())) {
 // invalid color
} else {
  // valid color
}
```

<sup>`checkHex` function taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852545/if-color-value-is-not-valid-javascript/14853006#14853006)</sup>

Comment: It crashes when I run the script because it states that "Discord" isn't declared. Also is the "colorArg" where I'm supposed to input the user defined variable?

Comment: Yes, it's the user defined variable. Also, you can define `Discord` with `const Discord = require("discord.js")`

Comment: Now it never seems to fulfill the requirements, so now it's always false? I've posted a codeshare link below so you can see the bit of the code that doesn't work
[Codeshare](https://codeshare.io/9O1AmM)