# color handler changing CSS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make it possible to change the background color of pull quotes by using the `input type="color"` tag in a form.
my HTML is as follows

```
   <form action="change.php" method="post">
    name:  <input type="text"><br/>
    email: <input type="email" id="email"><br/>
     <label for="background-color">Choose a color for background :</label> 
    color: <input type="color" name="bgcolor"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

You see I was trying to do it in PHP by getting the color value from a POST , but I would reay like to solve this question in Jquery if possible.

Comment: _"to change the background color of pull quotes "_ What is "pull quotes" ?

Comment: a Pull Quote is a snippet of text that is displayed on the side in a box, and with larger text generally. It is a Jquery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with something like the following. You need an `id` attribute for you input. Then on `blur` event you will change the `div` background color with the input value if it is valid.

Also, you have to include jQuery in html `<head>`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8roeoqb1/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" maxlength="6" placeholder="Hex representation of the color">
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bgcolor').on('change', function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        var isOk  = /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test('#'+color)
        if (isOk) { //If input is a valid representation of a color
            $('#your_div_id').css('background-color', '#'+color);
        }
    });
});
```

isOk regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027423/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-hex-color-representation).

---

---

Or using `type="color"`:

HTML:

```
<input type="color" name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" value="">
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bgcolor').on('change', function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('#your_div_id').css('background-color', color);
    });
});
```

---

---

---

**UPDATE**:

Move the following inside `$(document).ready(function () {` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('span.pq').each(function () {
        var quote = $(this).clone();
        quote.removeClass('pq');
        quote.addClass('pullquote');
        $(this).before(quote);
    }); //end each

    $('#note').draggable();

    $('#bgcolor1').on('change', function () {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('#id1').css('background-color', color);
    });

    $('#bgcolor2').on('change', function () {
        var color = $(this).val();
        var isOk = /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test('#' + color)
        if (isOk) { //If input is a valid representation of a color
            $('#id1').css('background-color', '#' + color);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was able to use this as a guide to get my project working as intended and your help was greatly appreciated!

Comment: Great! I 'm glad i helped you.

Comment: I can get it to work in JSfiddle, but when I copy that code over to a live site, it says that color is not defined. I don't know why that is. I have even copied all the code straight over from the fiddle.

Comment: Do you include jQuery in your script?

Comment: I did. I was using 1.11.0 and I tried that in fiddle. It worked, I tried updating to 2.x whatever you were using. I also have the draggable that the form is in. the draggable does not work in fiddle, does live. The color change does not work live, but does in fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Griehle/eet7cbuL/14/

Comment: I tested it. It works fine but you really messed up the jQuery. Check my updated answer.

Comment: You have to bind events in $(document).ready(function() {}); to take place.