# Replace statement not working for different html tag color retrieving from service

Tags: javascript, replace

I have 2 statement coming in string as below

```
"<font color='#F7D122'>".replace(/color='/g, "style='color:")
```

will return

```
<font style='color:#F7D122'>
```

**but how can I replace below one ?**

```
"<font color=#F7D122>".replace(/color='/g, "style='color:")
```

will return

```
 <font color=#F7D122>
```

but Instead I want return as

```
<font style='color:#F7D122'>
```

**In second replace statement you can find that string does not contain single quotes**

Comment: Your regex has a random `'` in it, remove that and it should work `/color=/g`

Comment: @Liam but at ending point also I need single quotes

Comment: I need my answer structure as  <font style='color:#F7D122'> in both the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regex replacement:

```js
// first version, with the hex color in quotes
var input = "<font color='#F7D122'>";
var output = input.replace(/<font\s+([^=]+)=(?:'(\S+)'|(\S+))\s*>/, "<font style='$1:$2$3'>");
console.log(input + " => " + output);

// second version, hex color without quotes
var input = "<font color=#F7D122>";
var output = input.replace(/<font\s+([^=]+)=(?:'(\S+)'|(\S+))\s*>/, "<font style='$1:$2$3'>");
console.log(input + " => " + output);
```

This is a more generic version of what you were trying to do, and covers any `<font>` tag with a single property inside it having the key=value format.

The regex trick used here is that we match either `color='#F7D122'`, with single quotes, or `color=#F7D122`, without quotes, in separate capture groups (`$2` and `$3`).  Then, we replace with both `$2$3`.  Only one will have any content, and it will be the hex color *without* single quotes.

Comment: You can see that for statement "<font color='#009900'>".replace(/<font\s+([^=]+)=(\S+)>/, "<font style='$1:$2'>"); we are getting 2 single quotes at the end point "<font style='color:'#009900''>"

Comment: @Mitesh I "get it" now.  One option here is to use an alternation trick to cover both formats of your expected font tags.

Comment: This is not working "<font color=#009900>".replace(/<font\s+([^=]+)='(\S+)'\s*>/, "<font style='$1:$2'>")

Comment: ...and that's not what my updated answer suggests to use.  Have you reloaded the page?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027423/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-hex-color-representation) to get the HEX color code, then use `$1`(first group) to insert that in the replace statement.

```js
const test1 = "<font color=#F7D122>";
const test2 = '<font color="#F7D122">';
console.log(test1.replace(/color=(?:"|'?)(#[0-9A-F]{6})(?:"|'?)/g, "style='color: $1'"));
console.log(test2.replace(/color=(?:"|'?)(#[0-9A-F]{6})(?:"|'?)/g, "style='color: $1'"));
```

Comment: "<font color=#F7D122>In this I am getting double quotes which is wrong</font> <font color='#F7D122'>This one is correct</font>".replace(/color=(#[0-9A-F]{6})/g, "style=\"color: $1\"");  IN this case both case are wrong I want some thing as <font style='color: #F7D122'>

Comment: I've changed the regex to match both `<font color=#F7D122>`, `<font color='#F7D122'>` and `<font color="#F7D122">`