# Split a list of colors containing rgba values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I have tags with a data-attribute containing a list of **hex colors**.

```
<span data-color="#ffffff,#000000"></span>
```

I currently **split** that list with *","* to get a real array.
But now there's starting to have **rgba colors** in the data-attribute of those tags.

```
<span data-color="rgba(255,255,255,.75),#000000"></span>
```

Of course, the split solution is not working anymore.
What would be the best work around?
I mean, I can verify if that the *","* doesn't have a *")"* before, but there must be a more elegant solution...

Comment: Perhaps start here:[how to identify a given string is hex color format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13624916/295783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean and simple regex using positive lookahead.

```
var string = "rgba(255,255,255,.75),#000000";
string.split(/(?:,(?=#)|,(?=r))+/);
```

return

```
["rgba(255,255,255,.75)", "#000000"]
```

Work with hex, rgb and rgba colors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple regex solution, I'm simply splitting by either ",#" or "),"

```
var string = 'rgba(255,255,255,.75),#000000';
var split = string.split(/,#|\),/));
```

Comment: return ["rgba(255,255,255,.75", "#000000"], there is missing the closing ")" of the rgba value.

Comment: Woops, you're definitely right, this solution isn't perfect.

Comment: this also wouldn't split a string like `'#000000,rgba(0,0,0,1)'`

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is better to use another approach: look for both color patterns by one Regexp.

```
// v - attribute value
var result = v.match(/(?:#[\da-f]{3,6}|rgba\(\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3}\,[\d.]+\))/g) || [];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gq9cLLu4/)

Comment: But with this technique, I'll loose the color order.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without regex would be to convert hex values to rgba values:

```
function parse(str)
{
    while (str.indexOf('#') >= 0)
    {
        var hex = str.substr(str.indexOf('#'), 7);
        str = str.replace(hex, rgba_from_hex(hex));
    }
    return str.split('rgba');
}

function rgba_from_hex(hex) // expects format '#rrggbb'
{
    return 'rgba(' + parseInt(hex.substr(1, 2), 16) + ',' + parseInt(hex.substr(3, 2), 16) + ',' + parseInt(hex.substr(5, 2), 16) + ', 1)';
}
```