# Find a hex color in string PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a database where users input a name with hex color codes, example: @#06A2AFMalo#0F0200keiro. Now i'm making a list where will show all records in database. I want to show this records with hex color. $tag is my string where have hex colors.

```
<?php
    $nadinha = mysql_query("SELECT logintag, tag FROM tag ORDER BY idc DESC");
    while($arapuca = mysql_fetch_array($nadinha)) {                    
        $logintag = $arapuca['logintag'];
        $tag = $arapuca['tag'];
        echo "<tr><td><span>" . $arapuca['tag']. "</span></td><td>" . $arapuca['logintag']. "</td></tr>";
    };
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, I suggest looking into prepared statements with mysqli_* functions, or PDO.

Comment: So you want to extract `#06A2AF` from the string? Have you tried anything yet? I'd suggest a regex. Are they always 6 characters?

Comment: @flauntster Thanks, im really new to PHP, i will search for this.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, always 6 characteres. I want to show [COLOR]Malo[COLOR]keiros. I tried put inside <span>, my friend told me that will work, but dont. Thanks for indication.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636350/how-to-identify-a-given-string-is-hex-color-format You'll need to use `span`s and `style` them.

Comment: In this example i used a simple record from mysql, with 2 colors. Thats another record, #F9F9FC|.-= #B732FFĐŘƗ₣Ŧ€ŘŞ #3244FFΔŁỮĆƗŇΔĐØŞ #F9F9FC=-.|, it has 4 colors, will this work?

Comment: Yea, you'll need to use `preg_match_all` to get all matches.

Comment: Im really new to php, i will try to use example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **Javascript** and do:

```
var prompt = prompt("What color do you want to choose?");
var div = document.getElementById('idgoeshere');
function changeColor () {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "prompt";
}
```

This would make it so that the color that somebody types in would make the div that color.

Comment: The problem is that i have many colors, and i need that colors show on text. Example: #F9F9FC|.-= #B732FFĐŘƗ₣Ŧ€ŘŞ #3244FFΔŁỮĆƗŇΔĐØŞ #F9F9FC=-.| need to show [COLOR].-= [COLOR]ĐŘƗ₣Ŧ€ŘŞ [COLOR]ΔŁỮĆƗŇΔĐØŞ [COLOR]=-.|

Comment: I am not sure what this is: ΔŁỮĆƗŇΔĐØŞ

Comment: ΔŁỮĆƗŇΔĐØŞ is a text from user input. Everything is a text from user input, i just need to show any hex colors on user input.

Comment: yes except you can type any way of color that is received by Css in this. RGB, hex, color names. You get what I mean

Comment: Well, not really. First i wil need to make a function in PHP to extract my hex, is this correct?