# Regular expression. How to make a custom condition

Tags: javascript

I need to make the condition, that will grab the color codes in format `#111;` or `#111111;` from string `str`. If be more specifically, I need to grab only color codes with length: 3 or 6 after '**#**', any other codes need to be cut off.

```js
var str = "color: #3f3; background-color: #AA00ef; and: #abcd;";

var reg = /#.{3}?{6};/; // for now I'm getting an error: 
                        // Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat

console.log(str.match(reg));
```

Comment: you might have to escape the `#` with a `\ `. Example: `/\#.{3}?{6};/;`

Comment: @TyQ. no, we does not need it, because # is not a special symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify a given string is hex color format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636350/how-to-identify-a-given-string-is-hex-color-format)

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase not, it's now the same :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a group with either three or six characters and a global flag.

```js
var str = "color: #3f3; background-color: #AA00ef; and: #abcd;",
    reg = /#(.{3}|.{6});/g; 
                        
console.log(str.match(reg));
```