# How to validate an array of hex colors is correct and discard the wrong ones?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

Currently, I only check if it's not null or undefined and I want to make sure that each hex color is correct otherwise discard the wrong hex and move to the next. If the format is completely wrong then just reset to an empty array. Any idea how I can do this type of validation?

Correct example of colors array(only 6 digit starting with # are valid):
`["#0283fb","#35363a","#f6383a","#9129c8","#38bdf8","#ded8d8"]`

Incorrect example of colors array(basically any non-hex color code or non-6 digit hex color):
`["#028s3fb","#325363a","#f64383a","9129c8","#13/12sc","#ded8d8"]`

If the localStorage string format is wrong or if the loop that checks each hex color fails then reset to [].

```
const colorsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorsArray") ?? "[]");
```

Comment: Have you looked into [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions)?

Comment: Please provide sample input that both has correct and incorrect entries, and provide the expected result.

Comment: @trincot I use those hex colors so basically any non hex color is incorrect entry. I want to check if the localstorage string is an array of strings ["something", "something], then split each string, discard the non hex ones, keep the hex ones. If the localstorage string is complitly wrong example: ["something" "some/"" "thing'] just reset to empty array.

Comment: Related: [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: Do you want to accept the alpha channel (8 hex digits)? Do you accept 3 hex digits (short notation)? `rgb()` notation?

Comment: @trincot only 6 digit hex codes are valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of hex color strings and you want to discard the ones that aren't valid, you could [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions).

Here's an example for filtering out everything except for valid 6-digit hex strings. (But note that 3- and 8-digit hex strings could also be considered valid).

```js
const colors = ['#ab432f', '#4ADEf9', '#gwhi32', '#2fad8923', 'foo']

const colorsSanitized = colors.filter(color => color.match(/^#[\dabcdef]{6}$/i))

console.log(colorsSanitized)
```

This regex matches a case-insensitive string that

```
^#                // starts with a #
  [        ]      // matches a single character that's either
   \d             // any digit
     abcdef       // or any letter A through F
            {6}   // exactly 6 times 
               $  // at which point the string ends
```

Comment: you say 8 digit codes can be considered valid but if you run the snippet, the 8 digit value is not returned.  Please update your regex.

Comment: @JeremyFiel I think you read my explanation too quickly. The question asks for only 6. I note that this only does 6, but out in the wild 3 and 8 are also valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the valid or invalid color codes:

```js
const colors = [
  // Valid:
  "#0283fb",
  "#35363a",
  "#f6383a",
  "#9129c8",
  "#38bdf8",
  "#ded8d8",
  // Invalid:
  "#325363a",
  "#f64383a",
  "9129c8",
  "#13/12sc",
  "#ded8d8c",
];

const hexColorRegexp = /^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/;

const validColors = colors.filter(color => hexColorRegexp.test(color));

const invalidColors = colors.filter(color => !hexColorRegexp.test(color));

console.log('VALID =', validColors);

console.log('INVALID =', invalidColors)
```

Keep in mind HEX colors can also use a shorthand 3-digit code (e.g. `#FF0`) and can use both lowercase and uppercase letters (`a-f` + `A-F`), and might even include an additional alpha channel (e.g. `#FF002299`).

Answer (score 0):

If `only 6 digit hex codes are valid`... Actually 3, 4, 6, and 8 are valid, so
in the `filter` function check if

- starts with `#`
- code is 1 + (3, 4, 6, or 8) symbols long
- each symbol after `#` can be parsed as HEX

In the snippet below console displays filtered valid ones;
each valid color paints itself, invalid ones remain browser default color (black?), and you might use this fact to determine if color is valid `rgba()` or `hsla()` or simple name like `red`.

```js
const colors = [
  // valid
  "#A0c", "#35af", "#f6383a", "#0829C877",
  // not valid
  "#02", "#XoXo", "#f64383as", "9129c8", "#13/12s"
];

const filtered = colors.filter(c =>
  c[0] === '#' &&
  [3, 4, 6, 8].includes(c.length - 1) &&
  [...c.slice(1)].every(d => !isNaN(parseInt(d, 16)))
);

colors.forEach(c => document.body.innerHTML += `<b style="color:${c}">${c}</b><br>`)

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Not sure what this code does. "#0183fb" is a valid 6 digit hex code and it doesn't pass your filter.

Answer (score 0):

Regex taken from this answer: [How to identify a given string is hex color format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636350/how-to-identify-a-given-string-is-hex-color-format#comment28551947_1637260)

Give this a whirl...

A function that takes an array of colors with a default parameter set to an empty array.

creates a new regular expression which validates 3 and 6 digit hex color values

```
^#                   // starts with #
  (                  // creates a capture group for the entire string
    ([0-9a-fA-F]){2} // creates a nested capture group for each set of 2 characters
    {3}              // validates 3 sets of character pairs are present
    |                // OR condition for the outer capture group
    ([0-9a-fA-F])    // creates a nested capture group to allow 3 character shorthand rgb variations
    {3}              // validates 3 characters are present
  )                  // closes outer capture group
$                    // ends the string match
```

maps over the values and returns an array of valid colors

```js
//const colorsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("colorsArray") ?? "[]");

const validColors = ["#0283fb","#35363a","#f6383a","#9129c8","#38bdf8","#ded8d8", "#0183fb"];
const invalidColors = ["#028s3fb","#325363a","#f64383a","9129c8","#13/12sc","#ded8d8"];

const validateColors = (colors = []) => {
    const hexColor = new RegExp('^#(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}|([0-9a-fA-F]){3})$')
    const listOfColors = colors;

    const valid = []
    if(typeof listOfColors !== "object") return []
    listOfColors.map((item) => {
        if (!item.match(hexColor)) return
        valid.push(item)
    })

    return valid
}


console.log(validateColors(validColors))
console.log(validateColors(invalidColors))
console.log(validateColors("#1223af"))
```

Comment: What does this code do? How is this better than the preexisting answers?

Comment: it works correctly compared to the other answers.  it fails correctly by adding a default parameter rather than assuming an array is passed.  it passes all the requirements by the OP

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to add explanation. How are the other answers incorrect?

Comment: none of the other answers implement any sort of type checking

Comment: i indicated that with this line `default parameter set to an empty array.`

Comment: it was..  `valid = []` is just declaring an empty array variable.  the default parameter is part of the function declaration.